# Give permission to hdf to remove directory

Tags: linux, hadoop

When I run `hdf namenode -format` then it wants to remove a directory `/home/hadoop/hadooptmpdata/dfs/name/current` but it have no permission to do it. How to give it a permission?

Answer (score 0):

you can use chmod to give permission

```
hadoop fs -chmod 755 /home/hadoop/hadooptmpdata/dfs/name/current
```

Comment: `failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectionException: Connection refused`

Comment: Edit your conf/core-site.xml and change localhost to 0.0.0.0. Use the conf below. That should work
<configuration>
  <property>
 <name>fs.default.name</name>
 <value>hdfs://0.0.0.0:9000</value>
</property>

Comment: now I get `your endpoint configuration is wrong.` In `coure-site.xml` I got also: `property> <name>fs.defaultFS</name> <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value> </property>`. Should I remove it?

Comment: i think you missed some braces or tags in your XML.

Comment: can you try
1)stop-all.sh
2)start-all.sh
3). jps
and show the output

Comment: the output is `5673 ResourceManager  6169 Jps  5854 NodeManager`

Comment: seems some problem with installation as there is no datanode and namenode are running